# Bind parent object's event to temporary child object's method

Tags: delphi, event-handling

I have an application where an invisible "Host" application object creates main form and main form creates temporarily a data monitoring dialog form.

There is an asynchronous data receiver in "Host" that has a trace output event. This event should be temporarily bound with data monitoring dialog form's method when dialog form exists and unbound when it is about to be destroyed.

I made a minimal equivalent to this application below. Could you check whether it is the right way to do so? Please pay attention to "Attention" comments.

```
program BindToTempObject;

uses
  Vcl.Forms, System.Classes, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.SysUtils;

type
  TBoolEvent = procedure(b: Boolean) of object;

  TDialogForm = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure BoolEventHandler(b: Boolean);
  end;

  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    _btn: TButton;
    _onBoolEventRelay: TBoolEvent; //Attention
    procedure _btnClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure BoolEventRelay(b: Boolean); //Attention
  end;

  TAppObject = class
  private
    _mainForm: TMainForm;
    _eventSource: TTimer;
    _boolState: Boolean;
    procedure _eventSourceTick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    OnBoolEvent: TBoolEvent;
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

var
  app: TAppObject;

{ TAppObject }

constructor TAppObject.Create();
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, _mainForm);
  OnBoolEvent := _mainForm.BoolEventRelay; //Attention
  _eventSource := TTimer.Create(nil);
  _eventSource.OnTimer := _eventSourceTick;
  _eventSource.Enabled := True;
end;

destructor TAppObject.Destroy();
begin
  _eventSource.OnTimer := nil;
  _eventSource.Free();
  inherited;
end;

procedure TAppObject._eventSourceTick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  _boolState := not _boolState;
  if Assigned(OnBoolEvent) then OnBoolEvent(_boolState);
end;

{ TMainForm }

constructor TMainForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited CreateNew(AOwner);
  Caption := 'Main form';
  _btn := TButton.Create(Self);
  _btn.Parent := Self;
  _btn.Caption := 'Click me';
  _btn.OnClick := _btnClick;
end;

procedure TMainForm.BoolEventRelay(b: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(_onBoolEventRelay) then _onBoolEventRelay(b); //Attention
end;

procedure TMainForm._btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlg: TDialogForm;
begin
  dlg := TDialogForm.Create(Self);
  try
    _onBoolEventRelay := dlg.BoolEventHandler; //Attention
    dlg.ShowModal();
  finally
    _onBoolEventRelay := nil; //Attention
    dlg.Free();
  end;
end;

{ TDialogForm }

procedure TDialogForm.BoolEventHandler(b: Boolean);
begin
  Caption := BoolToStr(b, True);
end;

constructor TDialogForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited CreateNew(AOwner);
  Caption := 'Dialog form';
end;

begin
  Application.Initialize();
  app := TAppObject.Create();
  try
    Application.Run();
  finally
    app.Free();
  end;
end.
```

Comment: This question probably belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Peter Wolf: Good idea. I flagged it for moderator's attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it that way, sure.  A decent separation of responsibilities between classes, so they don't have to know about each other.

However, in your particular example, since everything is in a single unit, and the `app` object is globally accessible, you could simplifly the code a little bit by assigning the `TDialogForm.BoolEventHandler()` method directly to the `TAppObject.OnBoolEvent` event and get rid of `TMainForm` as a middle man:

```pascal
program BindToTempObject;

uses
  Vcl.Forms, System.Classes, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.SysUtils;

type
  TBoolEvent = procedure(b: Boolean) of object;

  TDialogForm = class(TForm)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    procedure BoolEventHandler(b: Boolean);
  end;

  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    _btn: TButton;
    procedure _btnClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TAppObject = class
  private
    _mainForm: TMainForm;
    _eventSource: TTimer;
    _boolState: Boolean;
    procedure _eventSourceTick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    OnBoolEvent: TBoolEvent;
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

var
  app: TAppObject;

{ TAppObject }

constructor TAppObject.Create();
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, _mainForm);
  _eventSource := TTimer.Create(nil);
  _eventSource.OnTimer := _eventSourceTick;
  _eventSource.Enabled := True;
end;

destructor TAppObject.Destroy();
begin
  _eventSource.OnTimer := nil;
  _eventSource.Free();
  inherited;
end;

procedure TAppObject._eventSourceTick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  _boolState := not _boolState;
  if Assigned(OnBoolEvent) then OnBoolEvent(_boolState);
end;

{ TMainForm }

constructor TMainForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited CreateNew(AOwner);
  Caption := 'Main form';
  _btn := TButton.Create(Self);
  _btn.Parent := Self;
  _btn.Caption := 'Click me';
  _btn.OnClick := _btnClick;
end;

procedure TMainForm._btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dlg: TDialogForm;
begin
  dlg := TDialogForm.Create(Self);
  try
    dlg.ShowModal();
  finally
    dlg.Free();
  end;
end;

{ TDialogForm }

procedure TDialogForm.BoolEventHandler(b: Boolean);
begin
  Caption := BoolToStr(b, True);
end;

constructor TDialogForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited CreateNew(AOwner);
  Caption := 'Dialog form';
  app.OnBoolEvent := BoolEventHandler;
end;

destructor TDialogForm.Destroy();
begin
  app.OnBoolEvent := nil;
  inherited;
end;

begin
  Application.Initialize();
  app := TAppObject.Create();
  try
    Application.Run();
  finally
    app.Free();
  end;
end.
```

Comment: This single unit is just an example. In the original application all this is separated.

Comment: Then your original approach is fine.

Comment: @Paul I'd also recommend you to have a look at observable pattern as replacement for events. You can start by studying [ReactiveX](http://delphi.pl/zlot/zlot2017/prezentacje/ReactiveX_SG.pdf).